# Links are broken in production build in create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app

I am doing the most simple thing possible using create-react-app. I want to get the test application running on my website.

I create my **create-react-app** using this command.

```
npx create-react-app myTest
```

Then I test that it works when running the '*test*' script.

Yes. It works fine on the **dev-server**. I get the spinny react logo.

Next, I run the '*build*' script.

This creates a supposedly production ready collection of files :

[image]

I create a subdirectoy on my webserver to host this project.

**www.mywebsite.com/myReactTest/**

I copy over all the files using Filezilla.

I then navigate over to **www.mywebsite.com/myReactTest/** and all I get is a white screen.

Looking at the console, I can see that the paths are not quite correct.

[image]

What puzzles me is that this is supposed to be a production ready build? How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To run a static server using Create-React-App you need to serve it using Node.

```
npm install -g serve

# serve the build folder
serve -s build
```

See possible other solutions in [related docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#other-solutions).

Comment: i thought I just put my files on the server. You mean I need a node server? My server is not node enabled.

Comment: there is very little documentation there that helps me. I need to configure express?

Comment: Yes, but why would you? In 2020 you can deploy freely to basically everywhere. From netlify.com to codesandbox.io

Comment: exactly. i was under the impression create-react-app was zero configuration

Comment: I'm currently expoloring the theory that I have to set homepage in my package.json